# Excel VBA Do-Loop to copy and paste to populate empty cells in each row

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I need assistance on how to apply a suitable Excel VBA do-loop or otherwise to copy cell content and paste the next set of empty cell(s) in each row. As it loops through each row, it copies and paste only the next empty cells and again it copies the content of the next filled cell and paste on the next empty cells until each row is filled. I need to apply this to a table that contains about 5,000 rows. Any assistance will be highly appreciated. The original Table and expected Table result should look as follows:
[The sample Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIOsl.png)

Answer (score 0):

The below should do the trick. Please note that the below will overwrite the table with values only, so if your table has formulas, the formulas will be lost as they are overwritten with values.

```
Sub SuperUserHelp()

  Dim TempArray As Variant, x As Long, y As Long
  Dim ValueNow As Variant, SheetName As String, TableAddress As String

  SheetName = "Sheet1"   'Set your sheet name here
  TableAddress = "A1:E5" 'Set your table range here

  TempArray = Sheets(SheetName).Range(TableAddress).Value

  For x = 1 To UBound(TempArray, 1)

    ValueNow = Empty 'new row defaults to

    For y = 1 To UBound(TempArray, 2)
      If TempArray(x, y) = Empty Then
        TempArray(x, y) = ValueNow
      Else
        ValueNow = TempArray(x, y)
      End If
    Next y

  Next x

  Sheets(SheetName).Range(TableAddress).Value = TempArray

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, Judge! This is fantastic! It worked flawlessly.